# Error with pypasa and Glpk solver: [Errno 2]- No such file or directory: 'glpsol'

Tags: pypsa

This is my first time using Pypasa and Glpk Solver so my apologies if this error is very basic. Every time I run the optimization, I see the following error. Any help/comments are much appreciated it! Thank you!

Code: `network.lopf(pyomo= False)`
Error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'glpsol'`

Comment: Do you have `glpsol` properly installed and part of you `PATH`, i.e. is it accessible from within a terminal? -> Does `which glpsol` find the executable?
Also note that `.lopf(...)` is deprecated in favour of `.optimize(...)`.